# Show whether $\lambda$ an eigenvalue of $E$ is an element of ${\pm{1}}$ when $E^{2}$ = $I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When $E^{2} = I$ (where $I = n×n$ identity matrix), show that if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $E$ **then** λ $\in$ {$\pm1$}.

Comment: $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $E$ iff there exists a nonzero vector $v$ with $Ev = \lambda v$. So apply $E$ to both sides.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: More generally: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $E$ and $p$ is a polynomial, then $p(\lambda)$ is an eigenvalue of $p(E)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$E^{2} = I$ implies that $E^{2} x=Ix=x$. So we have to solve $E=ax$ such that $a^2=1$ since

$E^{2} x=Ix=x=EEx=Eax=aax$. And the only values for $a$ are one and negative one

($a^2=1$). IF $a$ is an eigenvalue of E

Answer (score 1):

If $x\neq 0$ and $Ex=\lambda x$ then $x=E^2x=\lambda^2 x$, so $(\lambda^2-1)x=0$.

Comment: For this level of question, I would emphasize why $x$ is not zero.